# Maxima: equations: eliminate variable inside diff() expression

Tags: substitution, maxima, equation-solving, differentiation

I have this code:

```
(%i3)depends([y,x],t)$
     eqsp: [y=2*x,
     v=diff(y,t,1)+y];
     eliminate(eqsp,[y]);

(eqsp)  [y=2*x,v='diff(y,t,1)+y]
(%o3)   [-'diff(y,t,1)-2*x+v]
```

And this is a picture for better visualization:
[PNG of code in wxMaxima](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtvko.png)

I was expecting that Maxima would perform a substitution of "y" in the second equation, and then differentiate to get "[-2*diff(x,t,1)-2*x+v]".

This is of course not the real problem (which has many more equations), it's just that I think I'm missing some concept here for Maxima to do what I want.
Thanks in advance for your comments. I'm a newbie in Stackoverflow and in Maxima, sorry if I made some mistake.

Comment: In this case, maybe `subst(y = 2*x, diff(y,t,1)+y)` has the effect you want.